# Prevent component Rerendening UseState Array - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

> Every time I add or delete a component the whole page reloads, how do I prevent it?
> When I use the HandleClick or the handleRemoveItem, the page reset and its components.

```
export default function Home() {
  const [PostArray, setPostArray] = useState<React.ReactNode[]>([]);

  let component = <PostSheet />;

  function handleClick(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (PostArray.length < 8) {
      setPostArray((OldArray: any) => [...OldArray, component]);
    }
  }

  const handleRemoveItem = useCallback(
    (todo: any) => {
      let newPostArray = [...PostArray];
      newPostArray.splice(PostArray.indexOf(todo), 1);
      setPostArray(newPostArray);
    },
    [PostArray]
  );
  const MappedArray = PostArray.map((e) => (
    <PostSheet key={uuid()} click={handleRemoveItem} />
  ));

  return (
    <DefaultLayout click={handleClick}>
      <Wrapper>{MappedArray}</Wrapper>
    </DefaultLayout>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sidenote:  a randomized key, `key={uuid()}` basically guarantees that your `<PostSheet  />` will be destroyed, unmounted and new instances created on every single render of `<Home />`. You're literally telling react, that these aren't the droids it's looking for.

Comment: That's not really a sidenote. That the whole note.

Comment: @super didn't realize that this is OPs main issue. Just something that jumped into my eye.